# How can I use the NDK to make games?

Tags: c++, java, android, ndk

I want to use NDK to use my existing C++ code for a game. I know there are two ways to use NDK:

- I can use Java to create GLSurface and opengl context;
- I can use NativeActivity class to entirely write code in C++.

Given that the documentation available about these two approaches is not great, I have trouble making up my mind.

What's the difference between these two approaches?

Comment: Have you searched online for documentation? Last time I tried using the NDK (a few years ago) the documentation was terrible and I gave up, but maybe the situation has improved?

Comment: Its not. I have been going through samples but all the samples are using NativeActivity class. I am relying on that right now.